# arXiv warning: Font shape "OT1/cmr/sb/n" undefined

Tags: fonts, arxiv

I'm struggling to understand why a paper I'm trying to submit to the arXiv has its fonts messed up. In particular, in some of the figures, it looks like the kerning on some text has gotten wider and the font weight has reverted to normal.

I see the following warning in the upload logs:

```
 LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/sb/n' undefined
(Font) using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

I'm no expert here at all, but isn't that Computer Modern, semi-bold, roman? Why wouldn't arXiv have that? When I compile either locally (with `latexmk` and TexLive 2022) or on Overleaf (with TexLive 2020, same as arXiv), I don't get this warning and the fonts look right.

I've tried a number of suggestions from browsing this site, like setting `\usepackage{bold-extra}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}`. The former appeared to do nothing, while the latter really messed up my document.

---

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[acmsmall,manuscript,screen,nonacm]{acmart}
\pdfoutput=1
\settopmatter{printfolios=false,printccs=false,printacmref=false}
\pagestyle{plain}

\acmJournal{PACMPL}
\acmVolume{1}
\acmNumber{CONF}
\acmArticle{1}
\acmYear{2022}
\acmMonth{10}
\acmDOI{}
\startPage{1}
\setcopyright{none}

\fancyfoot{} % Disable "Manuscript submitted to ACM" message

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Disable "Manuscript submitted to ACM" message
$\operatorname{\mathbf{def}}$ vs $\operatorname{def}$

\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like on arXiv:

[image: bad bold font]

and here are the logs arXiv's submission page shows me: https://hastebin.com/raw/eluboxuvar

Sadly, it does not give me access to the actual `.log` file.

This is what it looks like locally and on Overleaf:

[image: good bold font]

and this is my local `.log` file:  https://hastebin.com/raw/ruluridino

Comment: `sb` means semi bold. It may be that the font you use for drawing does not have a corresponding semi bold series. In addition, we don't know what you use for drawing. It is suggested that you give an mwe to reproduce the problem. Otherwise, it's inconvenient to help you.

Comment: @Clara - I understand that, and I'm sorry... if I could reproduce the issue locally, I might have a prayer of minimizing my whole paper. I also don't want to abuse the arXiv paper submission system. If it helps, I'm using the `acmart` document class, which sets libertine fonts. I might have misled with "figure". In this instance, something as simple as `\operatorname{\mathbf{def}}` in math mode renders wrong.

Comment: @Clara - I have added an MWE :)

Comment: sb cmr is not a standard font, and if  I use your example it does not use computer modern at all, it uses LinLibertineT.pfb and LinLibertineTZ.pfb ???

Comment: one would need the two log-files to see what is different.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - happy to provide them. Should I just paste them into the question?

Comment: for example, or put them for download somewhere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - done! They were too large for the question body, so I used a pastebin service. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to download the auxiliary files from arXiv's build. It just shows the "AutoTeX log" on the submission webpage.

Comment: well arXiv log is the important one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - no doubt... but arXiv truly does not seem to give that to you. I can't find any examples of other people on the internet getting them, so I don't think I'm being an idiot here. I'm certainly not trying to be difficult.

Comment: But where did you get the warning from?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - from the logs shown to me by arXiv, [which I posted](https://hastebin.com/raw/eluboxuvar). It is not the `.log` file, but apparently the standard-output of their tool.

Comment: yes sorry, I shouldn't read on a phone ;-). Well your log shows the version of the class, 1.73, and according to this issue this version has a bug affecting the fonts: https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/410

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - looks like uploading my local copies of `acmart.cls` and `ACM-Reference-Format.bst` worked. Feel free to write an answer, otherwise I'll self-answer tomorrow.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - sorry to forget my manners... **thank you!**